# LINQ2B POCO when db table name is unknown

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq2db

I have a requirement to use Linq2DB to pull data from different databases. In this example, lets just say it is SQL2012.

I create my POCO class like the one below

```
public class MyPoco
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I use linq2db to connect to the database and go and get the table, as follows

```
var q = from c in db.GetTable<MyPoco>() select c;
```

The problem I have is that although the POCO is correct in terms of the members, the user when they create the database can specify a different name (other than MyPoco). So, what I need to do is to ask the user the name of the table and then use that in the GetTable call, and map the results to my POCO.

How can I do this please?

Many thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 2):

```
db.MappingSchema.GetFluentMappingBuilder().Entity<MyPoco>().HasTableName(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given DataContext context and string tableName, you can just say:

var table = (MyPoco)context.GetType()
                           .GetProperty(tableName)
                           .GetValue(context, null);

var q = from c in table select c;

Comment: Hi Jaco, thanks for you feedback. If I try the following code then it complains as table is enumerable - the select statement wont work.

Comment: var dataContext = new DataContext();
                    var table = (EventsTable) dataContext.GetType().GetProperty("EventsTable").GetValue(dataContext, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
var ms = new MappingSchema();
var mb = ms.GetFluentMappingBuilder();
mb
  .Entity<MyPoco>()
  .SetTable(attr => attr.Name = userEnteredTableName);
```

Comment: Hi Reptile,I tried the above, but I get an error stating that the SetTable method is private and cannot be used there